# Is there an npm command to add a dependency to package.json without installing it?

Tags: node.js, npm

In other words, I want something like `npm install --save foo`

...but I **only** want it to update my package.json (adding the name and latest version number to my dependencies), and I want it to **skip** the actual installation into node_modules. Is this possible?

I tried `--dry-run` and this does skip the installation but it also skips updating package.json :/

---

(Yes, I could just edit the package.json manually, but I want to do this for about 30 dependencies at once, so I want to make use of npm's ability to automatically look up the latest version number for each one.)

Comment: i am looking for a similar solution since i am using docker to install the deps. did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `npm-check-updates` plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

`npm-check-updates` will check for latest version updates and update your package.json

To install `npm-check-updates` run `npm install -g npm-check-updates`

To check for updates run `npm-check-updates`

To update your `package.json` with latest version without installing run
`npm-check-updates -u`

To install the updated versions run `npm install`

Comment: That is similar to what I want, but I want to be able to add new deps, not just update the version tag on pre-existing deps